# Python Pandas - how to remove duplicates depending on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

So, I'd like to transform a table as this below:
[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrhIT.png)

into table as this here:
[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbiT2.png)

The goal is to remove duplicates and at the same time save information about values from the column "Value_c" in True, False notation.

Comment: any efforts? This portal is not for code request.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I've alredy tried, but not found the answer, so I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on `get_dummies` to get the desired output.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,1,2,2,2], "B":[1,1,1,2,2,2], "C":["Q","R","QR","R","QR","Q"], "D":[1,1,1,2,2,2], "E":["X","X","X","Y","Y","Y"]})
>>> df
   A  B   C  D  E
0  1  1   Q  1  X
1  1  1   R  1  X
2  1  1  QR  1  X
3  2  2   R  2  Y
4  2  2  QR  2  Y
5  2  2   Q  2  Y
>>> df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["C","E"])
>>> df.groupby(["A","B","D"]).agg(sum).reset_index()
   A  B  D  C_Q  C_QR  C_R  E_X  E_Y
0  1  1  1    1     1    1    3    0
1  2  2  2    1     1    1    0    3
>>> df.groupby(["A","B","D"]).agg(max).reset_index()
   A  B  D  C_Q  C_QR  C_R  E_X  E_Y
0  1  1  1    1     1    1    1    0
1  2  2  2    1     1    1    0    1
>>>
```